# How to change .css priority with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

I need to change priority of loaded .css files using javascript. I found that i can do this just by replacing position of < link rel="stylesheet".... >tag in the head element. This solution works fine in all browsers except IE. I am using the following code for this:

```
var firstCss =  styleSheets[0].ownerNode;
var defaultCss =  styleSheets[1].ownerNode;
firstCss.parentNode.insertBefore(defaultCss, firstCss);
```

So is there a better solution for such issue, or maybe somebody know how to make this code work under IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem maybe not in the best way but it works. I wrote the following code:

```
if (document.createStyleSheet) {
  document.createStyleSheet(defaultCss.href,0);
  defaultCss.cssText = "";
} else {
  firstCss.ownerNode.parentNode.insertBefore(defaultCss.ownerNode, firstCss.ownerNode);
}
```

I use "defaultCss.cssText = "";" to cleanup old CSS file, cause you can't get ownerNode of styleSheet under IE7-8(but you can do it in IE9) and delete old style sheet. So if you even load your CSS file to first position you will still have the same on the last position and it will be prioritized. I check it works under IE 7 - 9 and other borwsers, also stylesheet doesn't loaded from server again IE take it from cache.
hope it will be useful for someone.

Answer (score -2):

The order in which you load your CSS files has very little influence in how styles are applied. What styles are applied to a certain element is determined by the specificity of the selectors used in the CSS rule. A higher specificity overrules a lower specificity, even if the style with the lower specificity is declared later.

The specificity can be seen as a combination of four digits in the form (a,b,c,d) where a takes precedences over b and b over c and c over d. So (0,0,0,2) has a higher specificity than (0,0,0,1) and (0,0,1,0) has a higher specificity than (0,0,0,2).

The order of style declaration (i.e. the order in which style sheets are loaded) is only important if selectors are used with exactly the same specificity.

For Example:

```
A: h1
B: #content h1
C: <div id="content">
<h1 style="color: #fff">Headline</h1>
</div>
```

The specificity of A is 0,0,0,1 (one element), the specificity of B is 0,1,0,1 (one ID reference point and one element), the specificity value of C is 1,0,0,0, since it is an inline styling.
Since
0001 = 1 < 0101 = 101 < 1000,
the third rule has a greater level of specificity, and therefore will be applied. If the third rule didn’t exist, the second rule would have been applied.

Comment: This is quite a confusing answer, specially the "combination of four digits" part.
Anyway, the order of CSS files has influence on the styles of course. I understand what you mean, but maybe other people won't.

Comment: Check how to measure specificity here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: If you have multiple copies of the same exact selector, then the last one takes precedent. So why wouldn't this apply to this case?

Comment: _The order in which you load your CSS files has very little influence in how styles are applied._ That's not true.

Comment: is only important if selectors are used with exactly the same specificity. - ye you are right, i have exactly the same specificity in selectors, i need this for some reason. So i just need to change order of styles declaration.